# Funções setInterval() e load() e problemas no tráfego

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Então pessoal.. sei que o código abaixo esta bem desnecessário, mas eu apenas preciso saber de uma coisas, na verdade uma resposta...

O código abaixo em meu *site* serve para ficar fazendo *refresh* em um ícone de atualização em que aparece o número de quantidade de notificações caso algum usuário amigo tenha curtido ou comentado algo seu, como o Facebook. Porém, acredito que a cada *refresh* esta abrindo outra porta, porque na estatística do *site* mostra que esta tendo 1900000 de visualizações por dia o que acaba aumentando o tráfego do *site* parando com o servidor.

Então a pergunta: esse `setInterval()` com um `load()` que busca uma pesquisa no arquivo `refresh_notif.php` a cada *refresh* em tempo de meio segundo '1000', é ruim para o *site*?

```js
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
  function () {
    var urlLikes = $("#url_s").val();
    $('#4sNotificationsJewel').load(urlLikes +'/refresh_notif.php?user=<?php print $user_id; ?>').fadeIn("slow");
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar [Server-Sent Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events) ao invés de fazer pooling...

**Client-side**:

```js
var evtSource = new EventSource("ssedemo.php");

//Once you've instantiated your event source, you can begin listening for messages
evtSource.onmessage = function(e) {
  var newElement = document.createElement("li");

  newElement.innerHTML = "message: " + e.data;
  eventList.appendChild(newElement);
}

//You can also listen for events, using addEventListener()
evtSource.addEventListener("ping", function(e) {
  var newElement = document.createElement("li");

  var obj = JSON.parse(e.data);
  newElement.innerHTML = "ping at " + obj.time;
  eventList.appendChild(newElement);
}, false);
```

**Server-side**:

```php
<?php

date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");
header("Content-Type: text/event-stream\n\n");

$counter = rand(1, 10);
while (1) {
  // Every second, sent a "ping" event.

  echo "event: ping\n";
  $curDate = date(DATE_ISO8601);
  echo 'data: {"time": "' . $curDate . '"}';
  echo "\n\n";

  // Send a simple message at random intervals.

  $counter--;

  if (!$counter) {
    echo 'data: This is a message at time ' . $curDate . "\n\n";
    $counter = rand(1, 10);
  }

  ob_flush();
  flush();
  sleep(1);
}
```

**[Browser Support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events#Browser_compatibility)**:

**Chrome**: 9

**Firefox**: 6.0

**Internet Explorer**: Nops

**Opera**: 11

**Safari**: 5

**[Polyfills](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills#eventsource)** (Supports IE8+)

Comment: Interessante o script. Não tinha pensado dessa forma .. Vou dar uma estudada no assunto... Vlwuuu

Answer (score 1):

Obviamente quanto maior esse intervalo, melhor pra reduzir o tráfego do servidor. Você pode fazer algo tipo trocar pra `setTimeout` e aumentar o intervalo sempre que você procurar notificações e *não* achar nada; algo tipo

```
var currentInterval = 1000;

function handleRefresh() {
    /* puxa o dado... */
    if (alguma_novidade) {
        currentInterval = 1000;
    } else {
        currentInterval = Math.min(currentInterval + 1000, 60 * 1000);
    }
    setTimeout(handleRefresh, currentInterval);
}
```

O limite máximo entre consultas de notificação e a “aceleração” com que você aumenta o intervalo dependem do *tradeoff* entre reduzir a carga do servidor, melhorar a experiência do usuário e como é a distribuição estatística entre notificações que chegam no seu sistema.

(Eu acho que dá pra fazer algo com WebSockets e tal pra fazer o servidor *empurrar* as notificações pro cliente, mas eu não sei fazer isso; a solução acima te alivia no ínterim.)